# Badge Proposal: The Heisman

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, badges, badge-request

[image: The Heisman trophy]

When I was in grad school, we would say that one of our buddies got "The Heisman" when he was hitting on a girl and she overtly shot him down with the metaphorical stiff-arm denial. Just for fun, I feel like there should be a "Heisman" badge for a case when someone is denied or falls short of a badge or other reward in some annoying or embarrassing fashion. For example:

- When one of their answers is accepted, but then unaccepted in favor of another one.
- When they have the highest rated answer (and greater than X upvotes) for a question asked by someone who deleted their account before accepting an answer.

Any other interesting "Heisman" badge ideas?

Comment: I have another word for that. Epic Fail.

Comment: +1 for mentioning something football-related.

Comment: They look pretty hard to measure...

Comment: dubious. not implementable, at any rate.

Comment: So, should I close/delete this?

Comment: Jeff: Shouldn't you post that comment as an answer, so it can be accepted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Your answer is +50, but an answer with +1 is accepted.
- You send an email to team@stackoverflow.com and they don't respond back (have no idea how this would be awarded)

I would also propose renaming the badge to "Son of a..."

Comment: But if it gets voted up to +10, you get a gold badge. I don't see how that's so terrible for you.

Comment: If only they had a badge for you being the first to respond, and then two others response with your response, and the third gets the cookie. Maybe a "WTF...Lame." badge?

Answer (score 1):

Don't you know that recently the Heisman trophy winners have been busts in the National...Football..League (Had to say it like Ron Jaworski).

Comment: Not all of them. Some of them didn't even get there.

Comment: Example...Charile Ward was a point guard for the New York Knicks in the mid-1990s.